# Is javax.mail using two smtp sessions for each mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

So we're debugging some network issues were sending mail takes 5 seconds from telnet to the smptp server. The problem with sending mail with javax.mail is that it takes 10 seconds... We've turned on logging in javax.mail and it looks like it's opening two smtp sessions and the first one doesn't send any data. Could this be because of the 5 second delay? some sort of timeout? or is this how javax.mail works?

Our mail code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", _smtpHost);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

session.setDebug(true);

Message newMessage = new MimeMessage(session);        
newMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
newMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

newMessage.setSubject(subject);
newMessage.setSentDate(sentDate);     
newMessage.setContent(content, contenttype);

Transport transport = session.getTransport(SMTP_MAIL);
transport.connect(_smtpHost, _user, _password);
Transport.send(newMessage);
```

The debug output:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.xxx.xxx", port 25, isSSL false
220 mail.xxx.xxx ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino XXX) ready at Mon, 7 Nov  2011 09:15:00 +0100
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.xxx.xxx", port: 25

EHLO MYCOMPUTER
250-mail.xxx.xxx Hello MYCOMPUTER ([10.xxx.xxx.xxx]), pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-VRFY
250-EXPN
250-DSN
250-SIZE 256000000
250-8BITMIME
250 PIPELINING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "EXPN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "256000000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.xxx.xxx", port 25, isSSL false
220 mail.xxx.xxx ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino XXX) ready at Mon, 7 Nov 2011 09:15:05 +0100
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.xxx.xxx", port: 25

EHLO MYCOMPUTER
250-mail.xxx.xxx Hello MYCOMPUTER ([10.xxx.xxx.xxx]), pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-VRFY
250-EXPN
250-DSN
250-SIZE 256000000
250-8BITMIME
250 PIPELINING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "EXPN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "256000000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<tommy@xxx.xxx>
250 tommy@xxx.xxx... Sender OK
RCPT TO:<tommy@xxx.xxx>
250 tommy@xxx.xxx... Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   tommy@xxx.xxx
DATA
354 Enter message, end with "." on a line by itself
Date: Mon, 7 Nov 2011 09:14:55 +0100 (CET)
From: tommy@xxx.xxx
To: tommy@xxx.xxx
Message-ID: <145229992.01320653699737.JavaMail.XXX@MYCOMPUTER>
Subject: Test av html-mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
sending myself an email...
250 Message accepted for delivery
QUIT
221 xxx.xxx.com SMTP Service closing transmission channel
```

Answer (score 0):

javax.mail doesn't use *any* Telnet sessions. It uses POP3 or SMTP sessions.

Comment: oh, my bad. I'll change the title